# Hibernate @Formula recursive query with matching table

Tags: sql, hibernate, h2, recursive-query

I have a table with a ManyToMany relation with itself.
So there are two tables in my H2-Database:

```
supporting_asset:           supporting_asset_dependencies:
id | provided_csc           dependencies_id | supporting_assets_id 
------------------          ---------------------------------------
1  |  A1                           1        |          2
2  |  A3                           1        |          3
3  |  A2
```

I have a calculated attribute 'minCSC' and to calculate it I use the @Formula annotation:

```
@Formula(value="(Select min(sa.provided_csc) from supporting_asset_dependencies sad right join supporting_asset sa on sa.id = sad.dependencies_id where sad.supporting_assets_id = id group by id)")
```

This works fine, but depending assets can have dependencies of them own. With this I get a multileveled dependency tree. My goal is to get the minimum csc from this tree.

I tried:

```
WITH RECURSIVE tree(id, provided_csc, dep_id) 
AS (SELECT sa.id, sa.provided_csc, sad.supporting_assets_id 
        FROM supporting_asset_dependencies AS sad 
            JOIN supporting_asset AS sa 
                ON sa.id=sad.dependencies_id 
        WHERE sad.supporting_assets_id=2 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT child.id, child.provided_csc, childd.supporting_assets_id 
        FROM supporting_asset_dependencies AS childd 
            JOIN supporting_asset AS child 
                ON child.id=childd.dependencies_id 
    JOIN tree ON childd.supporting_assets_id=tree.id ) 
SELECT min(provided_csc) 
FROM tree
```

but I  get a 'Syntax error in SQL statement'. It seems like the formula is computed into:

```
(SUPPORTING2_.WITH[*] TREE(SUPPORTING2_.ID, SUPPORTING2_.PROVIDED_CSC, SUPPORTING2_.DEP_ID) AS ( ..
.. ) SELECT MIN(SUPPORTING2_.PROVIDED_CSC) FROM TREE) AS FORMULA0_1_,
```

It looks like it does not know the 'with recursive' command and tries to find it as field of the table.

How do I have to change the query to make it work or is there another way to achieve what I want?

---UPDATE---
I changed the query a little bit and on [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/s3yYkoAN2HMoA2rbu12cFz/5) it works for a SQLite DB. It also seems to work in the h2 web-console.

Comment: Does the SQL itself work?

Comment: @Andronicus I modified the sql statement and checked that it works. But Hibernate still messes up.

Comment: What's the error now?

Comment: Still the same. The SQL from the @Formula is still compiled wrongly. it does not know the with syntax.